# Upgrading Gradle version

Tags: java, gradle

I am upgrading Gradle version from 5.6.4 to 7.6.1.

```
ext {
    generated = 'src/main/generated'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory = file(generated)
}
```

The `setAnnotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory` method in deprecated the new version
[image: Gradle sources]

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.setAnnotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory(?) // where ? - Provider<File> file
}
```

How can I do this in the new Gradle version without using the deprecated method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/compile/CompileOptions.html#setAnnotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory-java.io.File-

> Use `getGeneratedSourceOutputDirectory().set()` instead. This method will be removed in Gradle 9.0.